# Container CSS Float Stepping

Tags: html, css

My containers step the first row, but when the float causes a second row to start the second row does not step. How can I prevent stepping?

[image: Div step]

HTML

```
echo "<div class='img-container'><div class='circular--portrait'><img src=\"" . $row["IMG_URL"]. "\" /></div><br><div class='caption'><h1>". $row["FirstName"]. "</h1><p>" . $day_month ."</p></div></div><br>";
```

CSS

```
.img-container{
width: 200px;
margin:1em;
display:inline;
float:left;
}
.circular--portrait {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
  -moz-border-radius: 99em;
  border-radius: 99em;
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  
}

.circular--portrait img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

Comment: Please share just the outputted HTML, not the echo statement :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `<br>` tags and it should be fine.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rocks2gL/2/)